# why this test fails while testing my api endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jasmine

this error

> Uncaught exception: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

```
import supertest from "supertest"
import axios from "axios"
import app from ".."
const request = supertest(app)

describe("Test endpoint responses", () => {
    it("gets the api endpoint", async () => {
      const response = await request.get("/api/images")
       expect(response.ok).toBe(false)
    })
})
```

Comment: run the command with `PORT=3001` before it.

Comment: A process is already bound to port 3000 which supertest is trying to start. Are you running the server in the background at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the port 3000 of the machine that is executing the test is already used. As a general rule, a port cannot be used by multiple application at the same time.

In your case, you probably already have another test running, or a local development server running on this port.

You can either stop it, or configure your test runner to use a different port.

## EDIT 1 :

As mentioned by [chovy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33522/chovy) in comment, you can prepend your command with `PORT=3001`